# Change visibility of a linkbutton in gridiew

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my page there is 2 linkbutton for download a pdf document,what i am trying to implement is if the versions are 0 then linkbutton should be hide from user.versions are coming from database.
How can i implement this asp.net gridview in c#.

```
<wuc:CustomTemplateField ID="CustomTemplateField3" IsRenderedOnReadOnly="True">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk8850" runat="server" Text="8850" CausesValidation="False"  CommandName="Print8850" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CaseNumber") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</wuc:CustomTemplateField>

<wuc:CustomTemplateField ID="CustomTemplateField2" IsRenderedOnReadOnly="True">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk9061" runat="server" Text="9061" CausesValidation="False"  CommandName="Print9061" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CaseNumber") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</wuc:CustomTemplateField>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by if versions are 0?  Which value/field indicates version?  Is the field in the query you bind to this gridview?

Answer (score 3):

If **Versions** column is an **Integer** value (0, 1, 2,...) , you can just use

```
Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Versions")) != 0 %>'
```

If **Versions** column is a **Boolean** value (true or false), you can use

```
Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Versions")) %>'
```

For example,

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk8850"
    runat="server"
    Text="8850"
    CausesValidation="False"
    CommandName="Print8850"
    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CaseNumber") %>'
    Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Versions")) != 0 %>' />
```

Answer (score -1):

I would make a css class with 'display:hidden'.  If your conditions are met, give the linkbutton that class with the cssclass property.  You should be able to do it the same way you're evaluating the casenumber in the command argument.

Comment: i am looking for where to check if visiblr or not

Comment: Using `.Visible = false` will skip rendering the control at all, from the *server* meaning cleaner output. While `display:none` will hide it the control from the user the content is still sent the the browser. In some cases this could also be a security risk.